# How to retrieve a sibling / neighbour control in a repeater after autopostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a dropdownlist with the SelectedIndexChanged event and `autopostback = true`. In the aspx on right of this dropdownlist I have a label. But these are inside a repeater. So when the SelectedIndexChanged fires how can I catch the label object in the server-side if the scope of the event is from the DDL and not the repeater.

**Aspx**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" 
   OnItemDataBound="repeater1_ItemDataBound" 
   OnItemCommand="repeater1_ItemCommand">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" 
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="dd1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
         AutoPostBack="true"  /> 
      <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code-behind**

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //How to get this label1
   //label1.Text = "Message" ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Control.Parent Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dropdownlist = sender as DropDownList;
    var label = dropdownlist.Parent.FindControl("label1") as Label;
    label.Text = "Message";
}
```

Or [Control.NamingContainer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx)

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dropdownlist = sender as DropDownList;
    var label = dropdownlist.NamingContainer.FindControl("label1") as Label;
    label.Text = "Message";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the sibling of the drop down list, like this:

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var theDropDownList = sender as DropDownList;

    // Make sure we have the drop down list before we try to use it
    if(theDropDownList != null)
    {
        // Find the naming container of the drop down list
        var theRepeaterItem = control.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;

        // Make sure we have the repeater item before we try to use it
        if (theRepeaterItem != null)
        {
            // Find the the label by name
            var theLabel = theRepeaterItem.FindControl("label1") as Label;

            // Make sure we have the label before we try to use it
            if(theLabel != null)
            {  
                // Do what you want with the label here
                theLabel.Text = "Message";
            }
        }
    }
}
```